# MVC n-Tier architecuture project dependencies

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, n-tier-architecture

I have mvc5 project having the following structure.

[image][image]
[image][image]

[image]
[image][image]

I have DbContext file in my DAL layer and  "ApplicationUserManager" class in the 'Entities' layer as shown below.

[image][image]

The 'ApplicationUserManager' class in 'Entities' layer has following code ie.

```
public class ApplicationUserManager : UserManager<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public ApplicationUserManager(IUserStore<ApplicationUser> store)
              : base(store)
        {
        }
        public static ApplicationUserManager Create(IdentityFactoryOptions<ApplicationUserManager> options, IOwinContext context)
        {
            var manager = new ApplicationUserManager(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context.Get<ApplicationDbContext>()));



Here, I am getting error :
1. The type or namespace name 'ApplicationDbContext' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?
2. The type or namespace name 'DAL' does not exist in the namespace 'MVCFinal' (are you missing an assembly reference?
```

Now If I add a reference to DAL layer to Entities, then whole lot of other things get broken.
How can I rectify this "ApplicationDbContext" error in Entities Layer.
What is the proper way of referencing the layers in n-tier.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you have a circular dependency which is not allowed and not recommended.

DAL depends on Entities **and** Entities depends on DAL

Consider of moving the **ApplicationDbContext** to the Common library and that way you will not have to reference DAL library in your Entities library.

Comment: yes I face circular dependency error but i learnt somewhere that AppDbContext should be in DAL as its related to data access.

Comment: @user1829056, you can alternatively move some of the entities classes that are used by DAL to the common library and remove its dependency on Entities

Comment: but in that case my entities(domain classes) will get scattered in multiple projects. i want to keep them in single project.